# How to capture a output of shell script using exec in tcl

Tags: tcl, exec

In my tcl script, i am trying to run a c shell script.
This shell script generates a `stdout` when ran from bash environment.
I wanted to capture the output of this script to a file.

I tried following method.

```
set logfile "Mylog.log"
exec sh check_syntax_nldm_new.sh  >$logfile
```

but this didn't work.

Is there any other method that helps.
Thanks in advance.
-Dan

Comment: But it worked for me. Are you getting any error ? Result of the script can be saved to a variable and can be then written to file.

Comment: It works for me as well. Is there an error message you are getting?

Comment: Well, it works fine .. i had syntax issues in my bash script..

Answer (score 0):

Some interpreters handle > redirection inconsistently.  Try echoing the output to a file handle instead:

```
set logfile "Mylog.log"
set lf [open $logfile w]
puts $lf [exec sh check_syntax_nldm_new.sh]
close $lf
```